# python AJAX FLASK GET refresh

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, flask, get

It is my first post here I always find useful information but this time my turn to be dry!

I am trying to display and refresh the data bid & ask on the html , the data are generated in a python module . I am trying to do that with jQuery and Ajax.

Here is the JSON I am sending, to be more precise I intend to send a list with each pair of currencies, here a single entry for `USDJPY`.

```
{'Bid': 109.355, 'Ask': 109.368}
```

Here is the python code:

```
import oandapy
from flask import Flask,render_template,request,jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

def getspot():
    oanda = oandapy.API(environment="practice", access_token="XXXXX")

    response = oanda.get_prices(instruments="USD_JPY")

    prices = response.get("prices")

    #posts =  {"Bid": biding_price,"Ask" : asking_price}
    posts = [dict(Bid=prices[0].get("bid"),Ask=prices[0].get("ask"))]

    return posts


@app.route('/_update_USDJPY',methods=["GET"]) 
def getUSDJY():

    return jsonify(getspot())

@app.route('/',methods=["GET"]) 
def index():

    posts = getspot()

    return render_template("basic2.html")

if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run()
```

Here is my html page:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<script type=text/javascript>
setInterval(                               
  function()
  {
     $.getJSON(                            
        $SCRIPT_ROOT + '_update_USDJPY',     
        {},                                
        function(data)                    
        {
          $("#post").text(data.post);                              

        });
  },
  500); 

</script>


{% block content %} 
    {% for post in posts %} 
        <strong>Ask:</strong> {{ post.Ask }} 
        <strong>Bid:</strong> {{ post.Bid }}
        <br>
    {% endfor %} 
{% endblock %}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Actually i realise i didnt say hat is wrong , it doesnt display anything and i have no idea how to debug the javascript

Comment: Where is `$SCRIPT_ROOT` defined?

Comment: I didnt define it where should i define it please?

Comment: Before you use it. I'm not sure why you are using it at all, but if you want to, you should set it to something.

Comment: how to define it? i am actually just trying to call my python function getusdjpy

Comment: Stop thinking in terms of calling Python functions; your Ajax script doesn't know anything about those. `getJSON` needs to call a URL.

Comment: oh ok so SCRIPT_ROOT should refer to my local host , how to specify that url in SCRIPT_ROOT just $SCRIPT_ROOT = http://XXX.X.X.X:XXXX/ ?

Answer (score 2):

add a script tag to our page that sets a global variable to the prefix to the root of the application. Something like this:

```
<script type=text/javascript>
  $SCRIPT_ROOT = {{ request.script_root|tojson|safe }};
</script>
```

your javascript code would be something like this:

```
  $(function() {
      $.getJSON($SCRIPT_ROOT + '/_update_USDJPY', {
      }, function(data) {
        $("#post").text(data.post);
      });
      return false;
    });
  });
```

in html:

```
{% block content %} 
  {% for post in posts %}
    <strong>Ask:</strong> <div id='post'>{{ post }}</div> 
    <strong>Bid:</strong> <div id='post'>{{ post }}</div>
    <br>
  {% endfor %} 
{% endblock %}
```

it's not tested just idea how it can be